# How to connect a Google Docs document to a Trello list?

Tags: google-drive, trello

Documents are kept on Google Docs but we would like to attach them to a list in Trello for reference or to work on the document. How does this work?

Answer (score 6):

Check out the work being done by Zapier.com. It is not free, but it is a very powerful service for integrating many different web services.

https://zapier.com/zapbook/google-docs/trello/

Answer (score 3):

There is no deeply integrated Google Docs support, but you can always include a link in a comment or in the description.

Answer (score 2):

Like Bobby Grace said there is no real Google Docs <-> Trello.com integration, at least not yet. In time there could be as Trello.com is working on their API and maybe someone will implement some kind of integration.

Meanwhile you can either link to the document or to a specific place in the document. If you want to link to a specific place, you can insert a bookmark in your document and link to that in Trello. To insert a bookmark: `Insert` and choose `Bookmark`. To get the link, click the blue banner and right click the `Link` and choose `Save link address`.

[image: Bookmark menu]

Answer (score 0):

You can include a hyperlink to the document by using the format:

```
     [ display text](url)

     [this is a link]( http://google.com )
```

Which will look like this:

[this is a link](http://google.com)

And if you create a bookmark as @Benregn suggested, you can link to a particular part of the gDoc.